# program reading in file erroneously

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Alright, I'm about to do something I hate, because my issue is requiring me to post my code unadulterated.

This is for a homework assignment. ALL I need to do for this half of the project is read in data from a file, store it, and print the data back out. The data (found here: www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/459841-final-fantasy-xii/faqs/42703 just incase I've missed something about the data) is just a list of rare spawns from Final Fantasy 12. There's s series of entries, which I have a set of loops in place to take apart and cobble into a pair of arrays.

The problem is that several of the entries are giving me issues with either printing data it's not supposed to, or putting data in the wrong spots. Several of the entries, where a series of asterisks denotes the difficulty of the monsters is supposed to be converted into a numerical format based on the size of a temporary variable that the asterisks are put into, are instead reading a DIFFERENT variable (not all of them, just some of them). Further, entries 51 and 65 aren't trashing everything they are supposed to, and instead kicking back stuff I DON'T want printed.

All it's supposed to do is take in vital stats about the mobs (Name, HP, XP, LP, it's weakness, what drops when it dies, what can be stolen, what is gotten from a Poach attempt, the original sprite used, how tough it is[scale of 1-5], and where it spawns at). Everything else is supposed to be thrown out. After that, it's supposed to print the stats I've told it to, and in the order I specified. It works for /most/ of them.

I've gone through the code a dozen times with the Debugger, and I'm still not even sure exactly where it's buggering up. Even so much as a simple "look at this part of the loop" would help tremendously.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void readFile(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7]);
void printData(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7]);

int main()
{

    string trash;
    string textData [80] [7];
    /* columns: 0 = name 1 = Weakness 2 = drops
    3 = stealables 4 = poach item
    5 = appearnce type 6 = location */

    int numericData [80] [4];
    // columns: 0 = HP 1 = XP 2 = LP 3 = diff rank
    // used 2 multi-dimensional parallel arrays to avoid 10 parallel arrays

    readFile(numericData, textData);
    printData(numericData, textData);

    return 0;
}

void readFile(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7])
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("80RaresFFXII.txt");

    string trash;
    string rankConverter;
    for (int i = 0; i < 169; i++)
    {
        getline(inputFile, trash);
    }
    //throws out first 169 trash lines, until first usale line.


    for (int rareReader = 0; rareReader < 80; rareReader++)
    {
        getline(inputFile, trash);
        getline(inputFile, trash);
        getline(inputFile, trash);
        // first three lines of EACH entry are trash: empty line,
        // rare number, and empty line

        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        // reads the portion 'Name : ' and trashes

        getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][0], '(');
        // stores name of monster

        getline(inputFile, trash);
        // throws away the rest of the Name line
        /* NOTE: this somehow fixed a different problem with
        entry 52 and on some how gumming up the works 
        look at cosmetic fixes when they crop up*/

        getline(inputFile, trash);
        // trashes emplty line after name

        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        inputFile >> numericData[rareReader][0];
        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        inputFile >> numericData[rareReader][1];
        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        inputFile >> numericData[rareReader][2];
        // stores HP, XP, and LP values

        getline(inputFile, trash);
        // trashes emplty line after LP

        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        if(trash == "\nWeak  ")
        {
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][1]);
        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        }
        else
        {
            textData[rareReader][1] = "None";
        }
        // one entry has missing line here

        if (trash == "Drops ")
        {
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][2]);
        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        }
        else
            textData[rareReader][2]= "N/A";

        if(trash == "Steal ")
        {
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][3]);
        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        }
        else
            textData[rareReader][3] = "N/A";

        if (trash == "Poach :")
        {
            getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
            getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][4]);
            getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        }
        else
        {
            textData[rareReader][4] = "N/A";
        }
        // note: poach exists on only some entries.
        // if/else statement exsists to compensate for variation

        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][5]);
        /* stores weaknes, drop items, poachable,
         stealable items, and the base sprite 
         image used for the rare */

        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        getline(inputFile, rankConverter);

        numericData[rareReader][3] = rankConverter.size();
        // takes in number of stars in Rare Rank, then coverts
        //the size to numerical form.

        getline(inputFile, trash, ':');
        getline(inputFile, trash, ' ');
        getline(inputFile, textData[rareReader][6]);
        // stores Location of rare

        if(rareReader > 79)
        {
            do
            {
                getline(inputFile, trash);
            }
            while (trash != "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            // throws away the rest of each entry as trash
        }



    }
    inputFile.close();
}



void printData(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7])
{
    cout << setw(20) << "Name";
    cout << setw(10) << "HP";
    cout << setw(10) << "XP";
    cout << setw(10) << "LP";
    cout << setw(6) << "Rank";
    cout << setw(10) << "Weakness";
    cout << setw(10) << "Sprite\n";
    /*cout << setw(10) << "Poach\n";
        cout << setw(20) << "Drop";
    cout << setw(20) << "Steals";
    cout << setw(20) << "Location \n\n";*/



    for (int printCount = 0; printCount < 80; printCount++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][0];
        cout << setw(10) << numericData[printCount][0];
        cout << setw(10) << numericData[printCount][1];
        cout << setw(10) << numericData[printCount][2];
        cout << setw(6) << numericData[printCount][3];
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][1] << endl;
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][5];
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][4];
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][2] << endl;
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][3];
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][6] << endl;


        /* columns: 0 = name 1 = Weakness 2 = drops
        3 = stealables 4 = poach item
        5 = appearnce type 6 = location */
        //copy of note for convenience in reading
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen a single one of the inputs being checked for success! That's the first thing I would change.

Comment: Erm... May I ask how I would do that, or for direction to a tutorial of some type that would explain it? First time working with input from a file

Comment: Just use `if (std::getline(in, line))` or `if (in >> value)` etc. If there is an error reading some input the stream will get into fail state. You may also want to make sure you are not reading input accidentally from multiple lines which is supposed to be on one line, e.g., expecting a `'('` which isn't on the line for whatever reason. I didn't look too closely at the logic but I don't believe in unchecked input...

Comment: Alright, I've at least isolated the issue. Some of the entries have a line that the others don't, and I HAVE an if-else statement that's supposed to resolve it and apparently isn't.